# Soap web service returns null within Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am calling a soap web service which does not work from within Visual Studio. It returns a null but soapUI returns a value. I am using a web service reference in visual studio. When I add this wsdl file to soapUI its works and return correct data in response, but in Visual Studio it does not work(Records Not Found).

```
   //request
   HotelBookingRequest request = new HotelBookingRequest();
   request.Profile = profile;
   request.PassengerDetails = passangers;
   request.HotelDetails = detail;

   XmlSerializer x1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HotelBookingRequest));
   TextWriter writer1 = new StreamWriter("HotelBookingRequest.xml");
   x1.Serialize(writer1, request);

   //response
   HotelServiceClient client = new HotelServiceClient();
   HotelBookingResponse response = client.HotelBooking(request);

   XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(HotelBookingResponse));
   TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("HotelBookingResponse.xml");
   x.Serialize(writer, response);
```

Comment: Are you definitely calling the same service? Check the properties of the web service reference to validate the endpoint you are hitting.

Comment: What do you mean "within Visual Studio"? Does it fail when you press F5 but work when you just run the .exe? And why are you serializing things?

Comment: @JohnSaunders. I Took it that the OP is getting different results when calling the service from SoapUI, than when calling from the test harness/client code in the question

Comment: @Nattrass: I take it that the OP should be more clear on what he means. In particular, he should clarify the significance of the serialization code.